# Why is my double losing decimal points? C++

Tags: c++

After I put my double in the if statement, my double loses its decimal place. If I input 1.0000001 for first and 1 for second. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    double first = -1;
    double second = -2;

    cin >> first >> second; // 1.0000001 >> 1

    if(first - second > 0 )
        cout << first << endl << second;
}
```

Comment: Please post exact input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  Which one is "my double", or is it both?  What do you mean by "loses its decimal place"?

Comment: Loses its what? http://ideone.com/JFmxO6

Answer (score 1):

Your double doesn't "lose" decimal places. You might as well ask why your initialisation worked when you didn't provide any decimal places in the first place.

`cout` chooses how many decimal places to show based on the value of the number. In this case there's no point in showing decimal places because they would all be zero.

If you want to show decimal places, play with [the I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double first = -1;
    double second = -2;

    std::cin >> first >> second;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    if(first - second > 0 )
        std::cout << first << std::endl << second;
}

// -1.000000
// -2.000000
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18624d4f4c1e5e8a))

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear enough. I meant when I input a number like 1.0000001 for first and 1 for second. When I try to display first and second in my if statement, why does it only display 1 for first when I inputed 1.0000001?

Comment: @dstone: I already told you: the stream picks precision according to its best judgement. Override it using the I/O manipulators. Did you read the information I linked you to? Did you try my suggestion? Meanwhile, this new information bears absolutely no resemblance to your question. So shall we try it again?

Comment: Opps, sorry haha. Didn't notice that was a link. Thanks. New to this.